# How can I make a Mockito mock perform different actions in sequence?

Tags: java, mockito

The following code:

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = Mockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class);
  Mockito.doThrow(new IOException()).when(mapper).writeValue((OutputStream) Matchers.anyObject(), Matchers.anyObject());
  Mockito.doNothing().when(mapper).writeValue((OutputStream) Matchers.anyObject(), Matchers.anyObject());

  try {
      mapper.writeValue(new ByteArrayOutputStream(), new Object());
  } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("EXCEPTION");
  }

  try {
      mapper.writeValue(new ByteArrayOutputStream(), new Object());
  } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("EXCEPTION");
  }
```

The expected output is

> EXCEPTION

right?

But I get nothing

If I then make the doThrow after the doNothing I get

> EXCEPTION
>   EXCEPTION

So It looks like it is the last mock that is the one that is taken... I thought it would take the mocks in the order they're registered?

I'm looking to produce a mock throws the exception first time and completes normally the second time...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Mockito can stub consecutive behavior with the same parameters—forever repeating the final instruction—but they all have to be part of the same "chain". Otherwise Mockito effectively thinks you've changed your mind and overwrites your previously-mocked behavior, which isn't a bad feature if you've established good defaults in a `setUp` or `@Before` method and want to override them in a specific test case.

**The general rules for "which Mockito action will happen next":** The *most-recently-defined chain* that matches all arguments will be selected. Within the chain, each action will happen once (counting multiple `thenReturn` values if given like `thenReturn(1, 2, 3)`), and then the last action will be repeated forever.

```
// doVerb syntax, for void methods and some spies
Mockito.doThrow(new IOException())
    .doNothing()
    .when(mapper).writeValue(
        (OutputStream) Matchers.anyObject(), Matchers.anyObject());
```

This is the equivalent of chained `thenVerb` statements in the more-common `when` syntax, which you correctly avoided here for your `void` method:

```
// when/thenVerb syntax, to mock methods with return values
when(mapper.writeValue(
        (OutputStream) Matchers.anyObject(), Matchers.anyObject())
    .thenThrow(new IOException())
    .thenReturn(someValue);
```

Note that you can use static imports for `Mockito.doThrow` and `Matchers.*`, and switch to `any(OutputStream.class)` instead of `(OutputStream) anyObject()`, and wind up with this:

```
// doVerb syntax with static imports
doThrow(new IOException())
    .doNothing()
    .when(mapper).writeValue(any(OutputStream.class), anyObject());
```

See [Mockito's documentation for Stubber](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/stubbing/Stubber.html) for a full list of commands you can chain.

Comment: Did not realise I had to chain them... ;-)